# how to share connector configurations between applications in mule esb?

Tags: mule, esb

Instead of using `mule domain project` (supports only sharing of connector configurations of `jms`, `http`... limited  connectors). I need to share connector configuration of `Object store` connector between applications. I am trying to access common data in multiple applications, hence I need this. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with session Objects you can send session data between different mule application.

Answer (score 1):

You could use configuration properties through a properties file in the domain project such as

> domain.properties

Example properties:

```
domain.value1=true
domain.value2=my text
```

. This file would be under the

> src/main/resource

folder in your domain project.

You can refer to this property file in your application as the global configuration element, property-placeholder. Example:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="..\..\domains\<domain project name>\domain.properties"/>
```

Simply refer to the property using

> ${domain.value1}